# removing data from memory

Tags: asp.net, memory, heap-memory

using ASP.NET and SQL Server 2005, I retrieve some sensitive data and display it on my page.
My goal is to get this data out of the heap as soon as possible.  I understand that setting the dataset variable to nothing/null still leaves the data in the heap.  I've found that for custom objects, I have to manually zero out content and for DataSets I can call `DataSet.Clear()`.

Are those the best ways to do it?

What about this scenario:
DAL calls SQL, fills a dataset, and returns the dataset(or pointer to the dataset in the heap) to the BLL.  BLL then returns that dataset (ie. the pointer) to the UI.  The UI sets the DataSource of the grid to that dataset.  When and how do I clear that dataset?

In Page_Unload, do I create a new dataset variable, set the DataSource of the grid to it and call .Clear()?

My requirement is not really to encrypt the data at all times, but clear it out as soon as it is not needed, without waiting for GC or having to manually call `Collect()`.

Comment: I am confused.  Only html, css, javascript (and yes viewstate) is sent to the browser.  The heap is on the server and garbage collected on the server.

Comment: yes, the heap is on the server and this a server-side question.

Answer (score 0):

What is your need for ensuring immediate removal of data from memory? As there is no perfect way to do this. A [cold boot attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack) would make the server just as vulnerable if the attacker has physical access.

Anything you send to the browser with your ASP.NET page can't be removed, ever (the browser can cache it, the user could save it to their HDD, etc.). Otherwise, if it is in the RAM on the server when the removal occurs shouldn't be that much of a concern.

The bigger issue is why is this sensitive data there in the first place. Especially if it isn't sent to the browser...

Answer (score 0):

Value types, like `int` and `char` can be cleared by assigning a new value to it.

Strings can not be cleared out that way. If you assign a new value to a string variable, it will just replace the reference and leave the old string object on the heap to be collected.

Calling `Clear` on a `DataSet` will not erase any data from the heap, it will just leave everything for the garbage collector. Even if you loop through each `DataRow` in each `DataTable` in the data set and assign a new value to each field, it will still just leave all the values on the heap. As the values are stored as `object`, each value type is boxed, so you can't erase the value by assigning a new value to it, it would only leave the boxed value on the heap and create a new boxed value.